# How to avoid calling ISelectionListener() twice on one selection?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

```
getSite().setSelectionProvider(tViewer);
```

`tViewer()` is a tree Viewer with various categories. On click of any category I need it to be displayed on a table Viewer that `implements` `ISelectionListener()` in the same way as given in various examples online. But, `ISelectionListener()` being called twice on just one click on tree viewer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your first step should be to try debugging to see where the two events are coming from. They could be two separate events, or the listener may be added twice for some reason.  Not really enough info in the question to tell.